# Как перевести в проценты от 1 до 100 диапазон возможных значений от 1.00 до 2?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как перевести в проценты от 1 до 100 диапазон возможных значений от 1.00 до 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

100% = 2, 1 = 0%, скорее так, значит 50% = 1.50, а формула:

> B + ((A - B) / 100 * K)

где

> A = 2, B = 1, K = проценты